# How can I install Gnome Builder IDE?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, ide

[Gnome Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder) is a IDE for gtk development, how can I install it on Ubuntu Gnome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Terminal:**

In order to install it you will need to add the `gnome3` and `gnome3-staging` PPAs with (you will need to run these commands in Terminal, to launch Terminal press: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run (to avoid problems):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And finally to install the package `gnome-builder` you will need to run (though you may want to restart your system after upgrading your system with the previous command):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-builder
```

This is because the `gnome-builder` is only available in GNOME Shell 3.16 and above, however because of how Ubuntu GNOME is packaged it is currently not available in the repositories and only if you get these PPAs.

Though for this to work you will need to be on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 as it will upgrade you to the next stable GNOME Shell version available to your system, and for 15.10 that is GNOME Shell 3.18.

**GUI:**

If you would prefer to use the GUI rather than Terminal though, search for `Software & Updates` in the `Activities Overview`:

[image]

Then go to the `Other Software` tab:

[image]

Click <kbd>Add...</kbd>:

[image]

Then enter `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu wily main`, press <kbd>Add Source</kbd>, enter your password if prompted, then click <kbd>Add...</kbd>, and do the same for `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu wily main`:

[image]

After you then close the `Software & Updates` window it will ask you if you want to reload your sources or something like that, say you do. After that you will need to upgrade your system by launching the `Software Updater`:

[image]

And updating all the packages it tells you upgrades are available for.

Once you have done that you may need to restart your system. And then you will be able to find the `gnome-builder` in the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image]

Which you can install by searching for it and then clicking the `Install` button, entering your password if prompt:

[image]

Comment: @Wilf: You can probably delete that comment now.

Answer (score 4):

Gnome Builder should be available for 3.16+. However due to the way Ubuntu GNOME is packaged you can't get it from the repos currently, and the only available build seems to be for Gnome Builder 3.18 for Wily, as currently the 3.16 build appears to have failed (from [here](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+builds?build_text=gnome-builder&build_state=all)):

[image].

You can get packages for Ubuntu, but for now atleast you need to be using Wily 15.10 with [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) - if the builds for 3.16 work this should work on on 15.04 as well. To add the PPAs:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Please note if you try to install just `gnome-builder`, it will likely to install some other aspects of the GNOME 3.18 (on 15.10), which is stable generally but not mainstream for Ubuntu yet, and can also break the default Unity desktop (should be fine if you want GNOME 3.18). It also may work better to upgrade GNOME completely as well when installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-session gnome-builder
```

From the PPA page:

> - You need to run '`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`' to avoid problems. Please read the output before entering 'Y' to make sure important
>     packages won't be removed.

You should also be able to install other Gnome Apps as well. Please note that not all may be at the 3.18 version yet.

There are other means of getting newer Gnome packages - you could try building the 3.16 version of Builder from [source](https://download.gnome.org/sources/gnome-builder/) though. (it may fail, you may need to modify stuff to make it work, if you examine the [current builds](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+builds?build_text=gnome-builder&build_state=all) it may be possible to find what is wrong and patch it). There are also other PPAs you can use ([example](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/testing)).

Comment: What about Ubuntu GNOME 15.04? You said only Wily, but upgrading to the next GNOME Shell version on Vivid will get you to 3.16 which you said had this software.

Comment: And why are you talking about a Unity desktop? The OP clearly stated that they were on Ubuntu GNOME...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda - Often with the Gnome PPA something in Unity breaks, so if the OP wants to use Gnome Builder + Unity it may have problems. Also only a build of Gnome Builder 3.18 for Wily seems to be available, though from source  you can get it for 3.15/3.16 onwards

Answer (score 2):

**#1 Using Gnome's JHBuild**

First download and install JHBuild

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file docbook-xsl build-essential git-core gettext
sudo apt-file update

git clone git://git.gnome.org/jhbuild.git
cd jhbuild
./autogen.sh --simple-install
make
make install
```

Then build and compile gnome-builder, along with all its latest dependencies:

```
jhbuild build gnome-builder
jhbuild run gnome-builder
```

The advantage here is that you don't have to deal with any external PPAs. All the required modules are built in a sandbox environment.

**#2 Compile From Source**

Download and extract the source.tar.gz file

`./configure` to find missing dependencies

You should manually resolve and install all required dependencies before you could compile.

Then run `make` to compile

Then `sudo checkinstall`

When checkinstall is used, you could simply uninstall by running,
`sudo dpkg -r gnome-builder`